# Setting Div Width Intelligently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, html

For a while, I have been trying to find a way to set the width of a `<div>` according to its content in an attractive way. I want to be able to tell the `<div>` to have a line break every so often, according to how many words are in the paragraph. So for example, if it's a long paragraph with 300 words, then the width is 500px and split over however many lines, but if it's 10 words, it's only 100px wide, and split over two?

I don't desperately need it but I have given up googling and was curious if anybody around here had any ideas.

Comment: You could probably do something with `min-width` and `max-width`...

Comment: is there pre-determined rule for the text layout to stick to?

Comment: A quick fiddle based on Andrew's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/DXvXy/.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Make the <div> have a specific shape? (golden ratio? square?)

Comment: Questions that say "How can I do this" without an explanation or what you have tried make it hard to give it a meaningful answer. Simplest solution, set your width with script based on the number of words and call the same function again when the content changes. You either would have to control all the code that could update the content, or you'd have to poll the div for content changes

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use this little script (move mouse vertically). It was originally written in ActionScript2 a long time ago.

http://jsfiddle.net/DXvXy/3/

```
/*
outerNode : block element with a helper wrapper element inside
Fiddles with the width of outerNode until it reaches desired height (maxH)
Width is limited between minW and maxW
*/
var fitToHeight = function( outerNode, minW, maxW, maxH ){
    var L,H,A; // Lo,Hi,Actual width for binary search
    var $set = $(outerNode);       // new width will be applied to the outer node
    var $get = $($set).children(); // actual width / height readout

    // Set initial width to the longest non-wrapping word (
    $set.width( minW );
    L = H = Math.min( maxW, Math.max( minW, $get.width())); // longest word

    // grow the width until height falls below maxH
    while( $get.height() > maxH && H < maxW ){
        // remember the width of the last too high box: it will be the lower limit for bin.search
        L = H;
        H = Math.min( H*2, maxW ); // limited grow of upper limit
        $set.width( H );
    }
    H = Math.min( maxW, $get.width() );

    // binary search for the ideal width where height just falls below maxH
    do{
        A = Math.round( ( H + L )/2 );
        $set.width( A );
        if( $get.height() > maxH ) L=A; else H=A;
    }while( H - L > 1 );

    // width might be smaller by a subpixel, so increment it to guarantee maximum height
    if( $get.height() > maxH )
        $set.width( A+1 );

    // set block's height if necessary
    $set.height( maxH );
};


jQuery.fn.fitToHeight = function( minW, maxW, maxH ){
    this.each(function(){
        fitToHeight( this, minW, maxW, maxH );
    });
}
```

​

Comment: Some sort of explanation would be awesome. Just sayin'.

Comment: Some sort of explanations added :)

Comment: -1 I can't figure out how this is related to the question. OP is asking about div width based on number of words in the DIV.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how this code is useful. Your code changes height according to mouse position and does not look very attractive to me; lots of text outside of the boxes.